# How to guarantee sequential order with angular http rest api in for loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, api

I'm trying to create a form that allows you to create multiple resources in sequential order.

Example below

```
Floor 1
Floor 2
Floor 3
...
Floor 9
```

---

***The problem with the code is that the order is not guarantee.***

My code below

```
let startAt = this.addAreasForm.controls['startAt'].value
const name = this.addAreasForm.controls['name'].value
const newArea = {name: name}

for (let i = 1; i < (amount + 1); i++) {
  newArea.name = name + ' ' + startAt
  startAt++
  this.areasService.createArea(newArea, parentId)
    .subscribe(
      area => this.added.emit(area)
    )
}
```

Can come back like

```
Floor 2
Floor 3
Floor 1
Floor 5
Floor 4
```

---

***How do you handle async api calls to guarantee sequential order?***

Comment: Maybe you can `concat` observables inside `for` loop, and subscribe to a result after the loop is finished? http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat

Comment: You know, when you update the `name` property of the `newArea` object all previously set values are updated right..? Objects are reference type. Other than that i would recommend inserting promises sequentially in an array and reducing them by `.then() `stages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `async` / `await` for that purpose with the Promise resolve:

```
for (let i = 1; i < (amount + 1); i++) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        newArea.name = name + ' ' + startAt
        startAt++
        this.areasService.createArea(newArea, parentId)
            .subscribe(
                area => { 
                    this.added.emit(area);
                    resolve();
                });
        });
}
```

Remember to put `async` before your function. See this [**demo on StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-helmsb).

Comment: My http calls are using observables. Will this still apply?

Comment: yes, that will work with Observables as well. It will wait for one observable to complete, and then resolve the promise and execute the next iteration.

Comment: A live example would be cool, plunker is blocked by my company.

Comment: @Omzig I have updated the demo to StackBlitz

Comment: This is so much easier than Promise.all() and you do not lose scope from your front end. You do not have to copy your services into local var's.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, I don't exactly all your code from your services, but the main idea is this: In order to execute async code in order, you can build an array of promises and then to use Promise.all to take each result in the same order from the creation:
[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
let startAt = this.addAreasForm.controls['startAt'].value;
const name = this.addAreasForm.controls['name'].value;
const newArea = {name: name};
```

Keep your services into variables I don't know from where your context comes.

```
 const areasService = this.areasService,
    added = this.added;
```

Make a function that create a promise for your subscribe:

```
function createAreaPromise(newArea, parentId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        areasService.createArea(newArea, parentId)
            .subscribe(area => resolve(area));
    });
}
```

Than another function to build multiple an array of promises:

```
function buildPromises() {
    let promises = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < (amount + 1); i++) {
      newArea.name = name + ' ' + startAt
      startAt++
      promises.push(createAreaPromise(newArea, parentId));
    }

    return promises;
}
```

Then solve them with Promise.all, to obtain the same order from creation

```
let promises = buildPromises();
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
        results.forEach(result => added.emit(result));
    });
```

Here a live example:

```js
function random() {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
}

function makePromise(index) {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   resolve(index);
  }, random() * 1000);
 });
}

function buildPromises() {
 let promises = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  promises.push(makePromise(i));
 }

 return promises;
}

let promises = buildPromises();
Promise.all(promises)
 .then(results => {
  results.forEach(result => {
   console.log(result);
  });
 });
```