# Multiple Sequential API calls in Angular 4

Tags: angular, api, http-post, observable

I have an array of image objects.

```
console.info('gallery', galleryArray);
```

[image]

The length of this array can be different. I have to make a POST request on every item of this array. The next request must be executed only after previous request has finished.

So I tried to make an array of Observable requests like this:

```
  let requests: Observable<Response>[] = [];
  galleryArray.forEach((image) => {
    requests.push(this._myService.uploadFilesImages(image));
  });

  console.info(requests);
```

[image]

My service looks like this:

```
uploadFilesImages(fileToUpload: any): Observable<any> {
  const input = new FormData();
  input.append('image', fileToUpload);
  return this.uploadHttp.post(`${this.endpoint}`, input)
  .map(
    (res: Response) => res.json()
  );
}
```

The question is how to perform those requests, so that every api call goes only after previous has finished? Help please. I'm new to Angular.

Comment: does your `_myService.uploadFilesImages` return any promise or observable?

Comment: @Faisal It returns observable. See edit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the `concatMap` operator:

Example

```
const apiRoot = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
const urls = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  urls.push(apiRoot + 'posts/' + (i + 1));
}
Observable.of(...urls)
  .concatMap((url: string) => this.http.get(url))
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

The `concatMap` operator only emits after the current iterated on observable is complete. You get the results of the individual calls in the the `subscribe` block.

In your particular case:

```
 Observable.of(...galleryArray)
  .concatMap((image) => this._myService.uploadFilesImages(image))
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Angular 7 syntax of your example
import { of } from 'rxjs';
of(...urls).pipe(
  .concatMap((url: string) => this.http.get(url)))
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
and thanks for your answer

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async` / `await` for that purpose with the Promise resolve:

```
let requests: Observable<Response>[] = [];
galleryArray.forEach((image) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        this._myService.uploadFilesImages(image)
            .subscribe(result => { 
                requests.push(result);         
                // resolve the promise once we have a result
                resolve();
            });
    });    
});

// This will only be called once all the api calls have been made
console.info(requests);
```

Make sure you put `async` behind the method where you are executing this code. Link to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737338/1791913) for a similar question.

Comment: It seems that this is an awkward workaround, not an idiomatic way to solve this problem. In Angular every event stream is based on rxjs.