# Sequential (transactional) API calls in angular 4 with state management

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-forms

I'm looking for some advice to best perform this requirement:

I need to call 3 or 4 separate APIs/endpoints to add a user to our system (using a form).

- The first call adds a user account and returns an id.
- The second creates a contact record from a different endpoint using
  the previous id
- Then there may be one or two more calls to create other business
  domain records based on the previous steps.

I have read through a few of the questions concerning multi - sequential requests: [Multiple Sequential API calls in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814808/multiple-sequential-api-calls-in-angular-4)

But I am wondering how to make the collection of calls perform like a transaction so if any of the steps fail (e.g. email regex in step 2) I can manage the error and also keep track of the step I'm on so I can continue from there as opposed to starting all over again.

I considered a combination of the answer I linked to and localStorage - is there a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In general this can be achieved with `concatMap`, `do` and `merge` operators:

```
this.formSubmit$
  .concatMap(formData => this.http.post(...).map(user => user.id))
  .do(id => /* save id here */)
  .merge(this.recoverWithId$) // continue from here if you already have an id

  .concatMap(id => this.http.post(...))
  .do(id => /* save whatever you need here */)
  .merge(this.recoverWithWhatever$) // continue from here if already have whatever

  ...
  .retry()
  .subscribe()
```

If any of the `this.http.post` emit an error it'll be propagated further and all subsequent steps will be skipped. Also the chain will dispose so that's why I used `retry()` before `subscribe().`

You could also use the `catch` operator but it really depends on what behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance - .merge(this.recoverWithId$) <- is this a variable (the saved id) or a function that points to the previously saved id? Thank you!

Comment: `this.recoverWithId$` is another Observable, most likely a Subject in your case where you call `this.recoverWithId$.next(myStoredId)`

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm still a bit confused about the merge operator, if I do .merge(this.recoverWithContactId.next('123')) that doesn't work because it's a void method and even .merge(id => '123') the following .concatMap doesn't receive the id param. I'm obviously going about this the wrong way! My recoverWithContactId is a new Subject();

Comment: return this.http.put(apiUrl + '/api', msg)
            .map((res: any) => {
                return res.ContactId
            }).do((id) => {
                localStorage.setItem('contactid', id);
            })
            .merge(id => this.recoverWithId.next(localStorage.getItem('contactid')))
            .concatMap(contactid => {
                return this.http.....
                }

Comment: hey, If lets say it successful creates the user and gets the Id, and then it fails in the id contact record creation, then lets say I have the scenario where in that case I want to rollback my first step, how would I do it?