# Call typescript function sequentially : Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written below function in Typescript:-

```
AdjustSpinAndGetAmbiguityAnalysisResult() {
        this.cssRefreshSpin = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin";
        this.GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult();
        this.cssRefreshSpin = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh";
    }
```

This function is calling :- `GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult();`

But I want to assign `this.cssRefreshSpin = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh";`

when function `GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult()` completely executes.

What can be done for this?

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737338/1791913

Comment: what does `GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult` return ?

Comment: That's what will already happen. I'm assuming your `GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult` is returning a promise, and I'm curious why you decided to leave that information out. If it is indeed a promise, then a quick google should solve this for you. Also, why did you tag this C# and .NET? It has nothing to do with either.

Comment: GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult is calling webservice and returning list of data

Comment: @Faisal when wrtten async await :- Async functions are not available when targetting to ECMA script6 and higher framework

Comment: If your `GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult` do some asynchronous work, maybe you should define a callback for it, and transform what you want to do via callback.

Comment: What does the **function** returns ? `Promise` or `Observable` ? async and await are transpiled if you target ES3,5,6 or more with typescript 2.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Subject for that.

It's part of rxjs and can be used as followed:

```
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

let subject = new Subject();
subject.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
subject.next('hello');
```