# How to call multiple methods on a button click using Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, click, angular5

i am using angular 5 and facing a problem. i want to submit (click) event and call  two or multiple method one bye one. Please give me idea or solution so that i can submit a (click) event and call two or multiple method.

such as

**.html file**

```
   <button (click)="abc(); bcde()"></button>
```

**.ts file**

```
  first method  
  abc(){}

  second method method
  bcde(){}
```

is this a right way to do this. Please suggest me and help me to solve this

Comment: What issue are you facing ? Whats the error ?

Comment: You can call other `methods` from `abd()` like this `abc(){ this.bcde();this.cdef();}`

Comment: can you please tell me the correct way  to call multiple method.. i am new in angular 5

Comment: I had this problem on rest api calls, they would not call in order till i found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737338/1178375

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<button (click)="callall()"></button>
```

make one function and call all the function in that

function 1

```
abc(){}
```

function 2

```
bcde(){}
```

call both in common function

```
 callall(){

        this.abc()
        this.bcde() 
}
```

Comment: It's a use case that is best avoided raihan, as the others have already pointed out. Better to have a single method you call and from there call the other methods you want.

Comment: why should this use case be avoided? It can happen that a click triggers two differ actions and it's not bad to make that explicit.

Comment: I agree that this is a bad practice! They should be called separately too avoid multiple code smells and pit falls.

Answer (score 39):

you can also do

```
<button (click)="[abc(), bcde()]"></button>
```

Answer (score 9):

This is the correct way I guess. It is working for me.

```
<button (click)="abc(); bcde()"></button>
```

Comment: I tried this approach in AngularDart and it did not work. I had to make a new function that calls the other two.

Comment: oo waw that is a good input, good to know @Pi