# Why do square brackets around HTML-bound event handlers work?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following code snippet.

```js
function func1() {
  console.log('func1 fired');
}

function func2() {
  console.log('func2 fired');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="[[[func1(), func2()]]]">Click Me</button>
```

Note that the `onclick` event attribute's value is surrounded by multiple pairs of square brackets (I used three arbitrarily, but the number of brackets doesn't appear to matter).  The code works in Firefox and Chrome, but *why* does it work?  Is this standard and documented somewhere, or is it just the browser trying to be helpful.

Comment: While this is a super fun question in terms of understanding how JS is executed in HTML context, on a practical note: don't use `onclick`, and don't teach `onclick`. Get that button on the JS side in a script loaded with the `defer` attribute (yes, that's even supported by old IE versions) and use `button.addEventListener("click", ...)` instead.

Comment: it's working too for `<button onclick="[[[[[[[[[[[[func1(), func2()]]]]]]]]]]]]">Click Me</button>`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't actually use this and maybe I should have pointed it out in the question.  I actually found this snippet in [another question] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54154706/3977276) and it piqued my interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because expressions can be used as statements in JavaScript. So it's creating nested arrays of the results of the function calls, but not doing anything with those arrays.

For the same reason you could write:

```
function func3() {
    [[[func1(), func2()]]];
}
func3();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What's not making sense to me is why the functions `func1` and `func2` are not called on page load.  Simply writing `[func1(), func2()]` causes the two functions to be invoked immediately, so why are the function not invoked immediately when wired up against an event listener attribute?

Comment: Because none of the code inside `onclick` is run until you click.

Comment: Why do you think it's different because they're in an array? `onclick="func1(); func2()"` won't run the functions until you click.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that makes sense.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The browser will construct a function from the attribute value, using the text of the attribute as the code of the function. In your case, that'll be a function that looks like

```
function madeByBrowser(event) {
  [[[ func1(), func2() ]]];
}
```

That is legal JavaScript. The function contains a single expression, an array initializer. A side effect of evaluating that array initializer is to call the two functions.

(The actual constructed function won't be *exactly* like that, and there are some odd and often problematic details about the implicit scope of the code in the function. It's close enough for the purposes of this question.)